How can I pass two different RenderFragments to a component and render those in different locations
I am creating a simple table component that has two parts header and the body.
So from user's(developer) perspective this is what I am trying to do.
Client.razor
<Table>
    <THeader>
        <Th>Col 1</Th>
        <Th>Col 2</Th>
        <Th>Col 3</Th>
    </THeader>
    @foreach (var eachData in Data)
    {
        <Tr>
            <td>@eachData.x</td>
            <td>@eachData.y</td>
            <td>@eachData.z</td>
        </Tr>
    }
</Table>

THeader.razor
<thead>
    <tr>
        @ChildContent
    </tr>
</thead>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}

Table.razor
<table>
    @ChildContentHeader
    <tbody>
        @ChildContent
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContentHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter] 
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}

My approach is wrong because everything inside the tag <THeader> is rendering under the <tbody> of the Table.razor along with the content of the <Tr> from the Client.razor, because the @ChildContent is placed under <tbody> of the Table.razor. This is not what I want to do.
What I am trying to do here is to render the <THeader> part at the @ChildContentHeader of the Table.razor. How to do that.

The problem is that you are mixing RenderFragments and components. In the posted code, ChildContentHeader is never used.
A fix, with explicit  <Header> and <Body> tags:
<Table>
  <Header>
    <THeader>
        <Th>Col 1</Th>
        <Th>Col 2</Th>
        <Th>Col 3</Th>
    </THeader>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    @foreach (var eachData in Data)
    {
        <Tr>
            <td>@eachData.x</td>
            <td>@eachData.y</td>
            <td>@eachData.z</td>
        </Tr>
    }
  <Body>
</Table>

and then rename the parameters in Table.razor :
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }

You'll probably want to refactr this a little and eliminate the THeader component.
Also watch your casing, <Th> should be a Blazor component, use <th> to safely mark it as html.
